# SQL querying to get every possible link

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a scheme with three tables with the following structure

```
donuts (name: string, price: integer) 
grocery (no: string, gname: string, credit: integer) 
distributor (dname: string, gno: string, deliverydate: date)
```

distributor.dname and distributor.gno are foreign keys that reference donuts and grocery which keys are name and no respectivey
I am having trouble with 2 queries I am trying to write:

1. I am trying to query the names of all donuts who are in every "Vons" or "Smiths" grocery store. (specified in gname)

I tried

```
SELECT d.name
FROM donuts d, grocery g, distributor dd
WHERE d.name = dd.cname
       AND dd.gno = g.no
       AND g.gname = 'Vons' OR g.gname = 'Smiths'
```

2. I am trying to query grocery number (no in grocery) shared by atleast two different donuts.

I tried

```
SELECT g.no
FROM donuts d, grocery g, distributor dd
WHERE g.no = dd.gno
```

This doesn't seem to return every occurence or account for OR. How could I fix my queries? I am a little new to sql please pardon my lack of knowledge.

Comment: You should really use Id values for your foreign key references rather than string values.

Comment: what server do you use `mysql` or `sql` ?

Comment: sql is a language, not a server.

Comment: @Nathan sorry, but 90% here interpret `sql` as **MS SQL Server** and all questions tagged `mysql` do not tagged `sql`.

Comment: I don't think that's true, but it's not really relevant to this question as it is clearly tagged mysql.

Comment: @Alex: That's utter nonsense. SQL questions should be tagged with both SQL and the DBMS, which is the case here. Other database questions would be tagged with the DBMS and not SQL.

Comment: @Jonathan Bishop: You shouldn't use a join syntax that's been out-dated for more than twenty years. It has been replaced then for good reasons.

Comment: As `distributor` doesn't actually contain distributors, but deliveries obviously, you may want to consider renaming the table :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are using a combination of AND and OR in your query and you need to use brackets to specify the [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), otherwise the OR clause will not be interpreted in the way you are intending. Example using brackets:

```
SELECT d.name
FROM donuts d, grocery g, distributor dd
WHERE d.name = dd.cname
       AND dd.gno = g.no
       AND ( g.gname = 'Vons' OR g.gname = 'Smiths' )
```

In the example above, the brackets ensure that the OR operation is only between the two gname values, and not between gname = 'Smiths' and the rest of the where clause.

2) Assuming the data only has one instance of each grocery - distributor - donut relationship, and each grocery only gets each donut type from one distributor, you should be able to count the rows and apply a HAVING clause to find where there are two or more relationships:

```
SELECT g.no, COUNT(*) as Quantity
FROM distributor dd, grocery g, donuts d
WHERE dd.dname = d.name
AND dd.gno = g.no
GROUP BY g.no
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Going off the first one, if I wanted to just check the name of donuts in in every store, I would just leave out the last AND statement? just trying to understand. It gets every result right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Your WHERE clause contains both the links ("joins") between the tables, and a filter criteria (for gname). This is actually an older style of writing SQL, the more accepted way these days is to write the links between the tables as JOIN conditions in the FROM clause, and have the WHERE clause only containing filter conditions - one of the other answers to your question has an example of this style of query.

Answer (score 1):

Try cooping up the last or in brackets like this, it might be just trying to look for your key joining with vons, then smiths without the key joins.

```
SELECT d.name
FROM donuts d, grocery g, distributor dd
WHERE d.name = dd.cname
       AND dd.gno = g.no
       AND (g.gname = 'Vons' OR g.gname = 'Smiths')
```

Comment: Does this return every donut name?

Answer (score 0):

My guess you just need `JOIN` tables properly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.name
FROM grocery g
LEFT JOIN distributor dd
ON dd.gno = g.no
LEFT JOIN donuts d 
ON d.name = dd.cname
WHERE g.gname = 'Vons' OR g.gname = 'Smiths'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Donuts sold in both Vons and Smiths**

There is no need to select from the `donuts` table, because all we need from it is donauts names, which we also find in `distributor`.

So we select from `grocery` to get the store numbers and use these to find dnames in `distributor`. We group by donut name and simply count their stores.

```
select dname
from distributor
where gno in (select no from grocery where gname in ('Vons', 'Smiths'))
group by dname
having count(distinct gno) = 2;
```

In case `dname` + `gno` is unique in `distributor` you can replace `count(distinct gno)` with `count(*)`.

**Stores selling at least two different donuts**

Your second query translates to

```
select g.no
from donuts d
cross join grocery g
inner join distributor dd on dd.gno = g.no
```

with proper joins. So you combine all donuts with all groceries first. Then you multiply these with all donuts distributed in the stores.

What you really want is

```
select gno
from distributor
group by gno
having count(distinct dname) > 1;
```

Again no need to query any other table; all information needed is in `distributor`.